# jquery hover: keep hover while firing child element

Tags: jquery, css

Sorry if it sounds like a basic or dumb question but I'm stronger in PHP&Mysql programmming than css&jquery animation (yet).
I am building a mostly css3 based menu for an application. The menu is positioned on the left side of the screen and has a small width (31px;) showing an image only (that is not included in the fiddle). When you hover one of the element in the list a css3 animation will make that element 187px larger showing some text. Some elements of this list contains a second level menu. What I have now can be seen on the fourth element named "Incassi & Spese". What I am trying to achieve is on the second item "Dati di base". The sublevel menu is on a wrapper_inside div that is absolute positioned under the relevant menu item and should slideDown when hovering the relevant text ("dati di base" in this example).
I have set up this javascript to do the animation but it is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wrapper_inside').slideUp('normal');
    $('.menu > li > a').hover(
        function(){   
            setTimeout($(this).next('.wrapper_inside').slideDown('normal'),1000);
        },function(){
            $(this).next('.wrapper_inside').slideUp('normal');
        }
    );  
});
```

Not working means that when I hover the item the wrapper_inside is not sliding down. The timeout function is made to wait for the animation on the first level menu to end before sliding down. I have set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leliofa/29jmhs05/2/) that display the full situation and can be found here. 
**The best would be to get rid of the js at all and complete the slide down with css3 transition but I have to admit I don't know how to trigger a transition on one element while hovering another**

EDIT: I fixed the syntax error and the hover now works. But I cannot keep it open while hovering the wrapper_inside. How to do it?

Comment: (offtopic) On mobile - you're forcing users to click on an icon and pray the page that'll open it the right one... (Are you sure it's the right UI design?)

Comment: Yes because this is a desktop replacement of an excel application that will run only in a intranet and the requirement is that it keeps beeing a desktop only app. I agree that on mobile it will be a nightmare! :)

Comment: $('.menu > li > a').hover( ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector is wrong:

`$('.menu > ul > li > a')` should become `$('.menu > li > a')` and it will work.

**EDIT**

You can hide the submenu on `mouseleave` like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.wrapper_inside').hide();

    $('.menu > li > a').hover(
        function(){   
            $(this).next('.wrapper_inside').slideDown('normal');

        },
        function(){
            var $that = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                if(!$('.active').length) {
                    $that.next('.wrapper_inside').slideUp('normal');
                }
            }, 100);
        }
    );

    $('.wrapper_inside').on("mouseenter", function(){   
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    $('.wrapper_inside').on("mouseleave", function(){   
        $(this).slideUp('normal');
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/29jmhs05/8/

Comment: You are right, and @Kamal too. it's because .menu is already the ul! The point now is on how to keep the .wrapper_inside visible while hovering on it...

Comment: sorry but still a small issue: when I hover just the first level it shows the second. But then if I move the mouse out of the first level without hovering the second level it (the second level) remains visible...

Comment: I did notice this and edited my answer again (added `.active` class). I think  that you are reffering to my previous code. The only small issue I can now see is when you hover on first level then hover submenu and come back to first level it slidesDown again.

Comment: I already had a css definition for a class named active that was conflicting now. Changed your name to something different and working in my site like in the fiddle. Thanks again!

Comment: Cool, glad I could help. One more improvement - I have fixed the issue mentioned in my last comment by checking if menu item is hovered. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/29jmhs05/10/ Note that this will work only with newer jQuery (2.0.2+)